# How can I get href links from HTML using Python?

Tags: python, html, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, href

```
import urllib2

website = "WEBSITE"
openwebsite = urllib2.urlopen(website)
html = getwebsite.read()

print html
```

So far so good.

But I want only href links from the plain text HTML. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Try with [Beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.yourwebsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

In case you just want links starting with `http://`, you should use:

```
soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")})
```

In Python 3 with BS4 it should be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

html_page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.yourwebsite.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup can not automatically close `meta` tags, for example. The DOM model is invalid and there is no guarantee that you'll find what you are looking for.

Comment: another problem with bsoup is, the format of the link will change from its original. So, if you want to change the original link to point to another resource, at the moment I still have no idea how yo do this with bsoup. Any suggestion?

Comment: Not all links contain `http`. E.g., if you code your site to remove the protocol, the links will start with `//`. This means just use whatever protocol the site is loaded with (either `http:` or `https:`).

Comment: A reminder for people came across this answer recently, BeautifulSoup3 is no longer supported in Python 3, the latest version would be BeautifulSoup4, you can import it with `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Answer (score 36):

You can use the [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html#example-html-parser-application) module.

The code would probably look something like this:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # Only parse the 'anchor' tag.
        if tag == "a":
           # Check the list of defined attributes.
           for name, value in attrs:
               # If href is defined, print it.
               if name == "href":
                   print name, "=", value


parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(your_html_string)
```

Note: *The HTMLParser module has been renamed to html.parser in Python 3.0. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to 3.0.*

Comment: I come to realize that, if a link contains the special HTML character such as `&amp;`, it get converted into its textual representation, such as `&` in this case. How do you preserve the original string?

Comment: I likte this solution best, since it doesn't need external dependencies

Comment: @swdev - I realize this is a few years late, but url encoding/decoding is how to handle that.

Comment: @Stephen How to find ahref links inside a tag table

Answer (score 15):

Look at using the beautiful soup html parsing library.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

You will do something like this:

```
import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
for link in soup.findAll("a"):
    print link.get("href")
```

Answer (score 10):

Using BS4 for this specific task seems overkill.

Try instead:

```
website = urllib2.urlopen('http://10.123.123.5/foo_images/Repo/')
html = website.read()
files = re.findall('href="(.*tgz|.*tar.gz)"', html)
print sorted(x for x in (files))
```

I found this nifty piece of code on http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code/regular-expression-re-findall and works for me quite well.

I tested it only on my scenario of extracting a list of files from a web folder that exposes the files\folder in it, e.g.:

[image]

and I got a sorted list of the files\folders under the URL

Answer (score 6):

Here's a lazy version of @stephen's answer

```py
import html.parser
import itertools
import urllib.request

class LinkParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        super().reset()
        self.links = iter([])

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'a':
            for (name, value) in attrs:
                if name == 'href':
                    self.links = itertools.chain(self.links, [value])


def gen_links(stream, parser):
    encoding = stream.headers.get_content_charset() or 'UTF-8'
    for line in stream:
        parser.feed(line.decode(encoding))
        yield from parser.links
```

Use it like so:

```
>>> parser = LinkParser()
>>> stream = urllib.request.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550')
>>> links = gen_links(stream, parser)
>>> next(links)
'//stackoverflow.com'
```

Answer (score 6):

Using requests with BeautifulSoup and Python 3:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get('http://www.website.com')
bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')
for link in bs.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 6):

This is way late to answer but it will work for latest python users:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 


html_page = requests.get('http://www.example.com').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, "lxml")
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Don't forget to install "**requests**" and "**BeautifulSoup**" package and also "**lxml**". Use .text along with get otherwise it will throw an exception.

"**lxml**" is used to remove that warning of which parser to be used. You can also use  "**html.parser**" whichever fits your case.

Answer (score 5):

My answer probably sucks compared to the real gurus out there, but using some simple math, string slicing, find and urllib, this little script will create a list containing link elements. I test google and my output seems right. Hope it helps!

```
import urllib
test = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com").read()
sane = 0
needlestack = []
while sane == 0:
  curpos = test.find("href")
  if curpos >= 0:
    testlen = len(test)
    test = test[curpos:testlen]
    curpos = test.find('"')
    testlen = len(test)
    test = test[curpos+1:testlen]
    curpos = test.find('"')
    needle = test[0:curpos]
    if needle.startswith("http" or "www"):
        needlestack.append(needle)
  else:
    sane = 1
for item in needlestack:
  print item
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is similar to others with `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`, but using list comprehension.

Because `find_all()` is the most popular method in the Beautiful Soup search API, you can use `soup("a")` as a shortcut of `soup.findAll("a")` and using list comprehension:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "http://www.yourwebsite.com"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')
# Find links
all_links = [link.get("href") for link in soup("a")]
# Only external links
ext_links = [link.get("href") for link in soup("a") if "http" in link.get("href")]
```

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way for me:

```
from urlextract import URLExtract
from requests import get

url = "sample.com/samplepage/"
req = requests.get(url)
text = req.text
# or if you already have the html source:
# text = "This is html for ex <a href='http://google.com/'>Google</a> <a href='http://yahoo.com/'>Yahoo</a>"
text = text.replace(' ', '').replace('=','')
extractor = URLExtract()
print(extractor.find_urls(text))
```

output:

`['http://google.com/', 'http://yahoo.com/']`