# How to download multiple files with urllib?

Tags: python, download, web-scraping, urllib

I know how to download 1 file by pointing the urllib to the specific file.

How can I download all of the files in url? which includes links that a relative non relative

```
#Code to download 1 file, which im using at the moment
import urllib, os
    os.chdir('/directory/to/save/the/file/to')
    url = 'http://urltosite/myfile.txt'#Download all files in this url
    urllib.urlretrieve(url)
```

Comment: Is looping what you want?

Comment: Yeah, something that will go through the site and download each file associated with .jpg, .gif, .docx

Comment: @Scott It seems you are looking for so called web crawlers (or spiders). One example is here: http://www.netinstructions.com/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-in-under-50-lines-of-python-code/

Comment: @MartinVseticka Im looking to download the files found in websites, Im juts not able to implement a method to download all .doc and .gif/.jpg files on a site as apposed to downloading 1, with the method on the original post

Comment: @Scott ... and it won't be easy without some effort - i.e. reading and learning. :-) If you need some advice, it's OK but "download files found in websites" is too general to answer *correctly*. There are many existing implementations for Python so maybe you can just try some of them or modify them for your needs.

Comment: I know its difficult, I've been at if for a while hah! Can you give my some advice on how to get started then? :)

Comment: This should get you all links on a webpage - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075568/99256 (for links that are not generated by JavaScript)

Comment: This actually helped!! Thanks!