# Find string between 2 chars regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-2.x

I'm trying to find URLs in html. This is the example I'm trying to match:

href="http://(.+)"(?:.+)

```
<a href="http://www.etf.rs/" target="_top">
```

This matches:
www.etf.rs/" target=

And it should:
www.etf.rs**

It's not important if it matches some rubish thing, but it's iportant that all URLs are matched. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-code?

Comment: I don't want it to contain http://

Comment: and some links start with https:// too

Comment: `href="https?://([^"]+)"`

Comment: Yeah, thanks, this works!

Comment: `<a href="http:&#47;/www.example.com">` … how important is it that *all* urls are matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.search`:

```
import re

s = '<a href="http://www.etf.rs/" target="_top">'
print re.search('"http://(.*)"\s', s).group(1)
```

Output:

```
www.etf.rs/
```

Comment: leave a comment if you don't like the answer, otherwise it's useless

Comment: you are welcome, my comment was for someone who downvoted without comment, it's hard to understand what's not right in the answer without a comment