# How can I find only the links that contain an href (any href)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to find all links in my soup that contain an href, regardless of what the href is.

I know how to do this, but I would rather do it in a simpler manner. Here is how I do so now:

```
links = []
link_list = soup.find_all('link', {'class':'abc'})

for link in link_list:
    if 'href' in link.attrs:
        links.append(link)
```

It seems unnecessary to iterate through all the links a second time as I am in the code above. Is there a way to do this with the find_all() function in one line of code?

Comment: `soup.find_all('a', href=True)`?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. How about is the attribute was something such as "class" or something that wouldn't typically show up? Would I simply put a similar key-value pair in the dictionary?
Like this: {'href':True}

Comment: It would be something like `soup.find_all('a',class_="my_class", href=True)`, I believe.

Comment: I forgot about class_, but what I mean to ask is how this would work if there was not a specific parameter for the attribute. If we were parsing xml data with custom attributes, how would we check? I'll modify my example above: {'abc':True}

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. First, if it's xml and not html, you may have to use an xml parser (like lxml). Second, the best way to handle it is to edit your question (or,even better, post a new question; SO doesn't like multiple questions in one...) with sample xml snippet and exact expected output.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get href links from HTML using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-using-python)

Comment: @akin_ai If you read the description, you will observe that this link does not address my question. Jack resolved it in his first comment.