# Python regular expression match start and end string and must contain specific word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I need some guidance with refining my regex. I have the source of a webpage, and would like to extract the href's from the page. the table doesn't have any ID's or class. I have decided to use regex, however my expression seems to be matching more than I want.
I have tried the following:

`http:\/\/(.*?)(?=.*showuri)(.*?)responseType=xml\">\/lnc\/`

my start is **http://** the end is **responseType=xml">/lnc/** and I need the middle bit to contain the word **showuri**

I am using Python 3

Comment: Maybe you should use a parser first to get all hrefs (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-using-python)) then filter the results on contains `responseType=xml>/lnc/`

Comment: Don’t use RegEx for this.

Answer (score 0):

The method I used for this is as follows:

```
doc = html.fromstring(text)
tr_elements = doc.xpath('//a/@href')
df = pd.DataFrame(tr_elements)
df.columns=['URL']
```

from this point, I will drop rows that do no contain "showuri"

Comment: thanks to @ctwheels for a similar method of approaching this