# how delete character(Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i want to delete character from my ouput like i want just the link
sorry for my bad english

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://cryptofaucets.cash/2021/02/01/best-free-bitcoin-faucets/'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
l = []
for link in soup.find_all('h2'):
    print(link.find_all('a')[-1])
```

i want ouput like this

```
https://satoshihero.com/en/register?
```

not like this

```
<a href="https://satoshihero.com/en/register?r=2eedd708" rel="noopener" target="_blank">SatoshiHero.com</a>
```

how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Either you can find all links inside that loop and try this

```
for link in links.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

OR

```
link.find_all('a')[-1].get('href')
```

Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075568/6695297

Comment: How does this eliminate the query parameters?

Comment: In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)

Comment: @HedgeHog Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 10, in <module>
    for links in link.find_all('a')[-1]:
IndexError: list index out of range  <--- can you solve this

Comment: @HedgeHog here my code -->                                                                                       
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://cryptofaucets.cash/2021/02/01/best-free-bitcoin-faucets/'
r = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
l = []
for link in soup.find_all('h2'):
    for links in link.find_all('a')[-1]:
        print((f"https://{links.text}"))

Comment: @JohnFitzgeraldKennedy This is IndexError that means when you're trying to access an element which is not present on that index. In this case link.findall('a') returns blank list and in blank list you cannot access -1 index.