# How to extract the html link from a html page in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urlparse

From this python code,

```
...
resp = logout_session.get(logout_url, headers=headers, verify=False, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

I was able to make an API call, and the response content is of this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>...</head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="title logo" id="header">
    <img alt="" id="business-logo-login" src="/customviews/image/business_logo:f0a067275aba3c71c62cffa2f50ac69c/"/>
   </div>
   <div class="input-group alert alert-success text-center" id="title" role="alert">
    Successfully signed out
   </div>
   <div class="input-group alert text-center">
    <a href="/saml-idp/portal/">
     Login again
    </a>
   </div>
   <div>
    <p>
     You will be redirected to https://idpftc.business.com/saml/Gy736KPK3v1aWDPECRZKAn/proxy_logout/ after 5 seconds ...
    </p>
    <script language="javascript" nonce="">
     window.onload = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.replace("https://idpftc.business.com/saml/Gy736KPK3v1aWDPECRZKAn/proxy_logout/?SAMLResponse=3VjJkuNIjv2VtKijLJObJIphlWnGfd93Xtoo7vsukvr6ZkRU");}, 5000);
    </script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to extract the html link:

```
https://idpftc.business.com/saml/Gy736KPK3v1aWDPECRZKAn/proxy_logout/?SAMLResponse=3VjJkuNIjv2VtKijLJObJIphlWnGfd93Xtoo7vsukvr6ZkRU
```

from this content, does anyone know how to do it in python ?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075568/2681662

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [beautifulsoup documentation](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree) has a variety of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

# resp = requests.get(...)

url = re.search(r'window\.location\.replace\("([^"]+)', resp.text).group(1)
print(url)
```

Prints:

```
https://idpftc.business.com/saml/Gy736KPK3v1aWDPECRZKAn/proxy_logout/?SAMLResponse=3VjJkuNIjv2VtKijLJObJIphlWnGfd93Xtoo7vsukvr6ZkRU
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import bs
api ="""your response above"""
soup = bs(api,"html.parser")
scr = soup.select_one('script').string
scr.split('"')[1]
```

The output should be the url.